# How do JSON.parse() and escape characters work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

Suppose I have an object variable:

```
var obj = {
    key: '\"Hello World\"'
}
```

Then I tried parse it to string by using `JSON.stringify` in Chrome devtools console:

```
JSON.stringify(obj) // "{"key":"\"Hello World\""}"
```

I get the result `"{"key":"\"Hello World\""}"`. Then I give it to a string

```
var str = '{"key":"\"Hello World\""}'
```

At least I try to convert it back to obj:

```
JSON.parse(str);
```

but the browser tell me wrong `Uncaught SyntaxError`

What confused me is why this is wrong? I get the string from an origin object and I just want turn it back.

How can I fix this problem? If I want do the job like convert obj to string and return it back, how can I do?

Comment: You might find what you're doing easier if you don't use `\ ` to escape characters in this case. If you alternate between `'` and `"` you don't need to escape. For example, you can do `key: '"Hello World"'`.

Comment: A string *value* is not the same as a string **literal**. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` will work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're tried to convert your JSON into a string literal by wrapping it in `'` characters, but `\` characters have special meaning inside JavaScript string literals and `\"` gets converted to `"` by the JavaScript parser before it reaches the JSON parser.

You need to escape the `\` characters too.

```
var str = '{"key":"\\"Hello World\\""}'
```

That said, in general, it is better to not try to embed JSON in JavaScript string literals only to parse them with JSON.parse in the first place. JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript so you can use it directly.

```
var result = {"key":"\"Hello World\""};
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var str = '{"key":"\\"Hello World\\""}';
```